# geo.Geoserver.GeoserverException: Status : 404 - b"No such workspace - geoserver-rest - Docker

Tags: python, docker, geoserver-rest-py

This question is related to docker and geoserver-rest. It is a part of a larger project but I have a created some simpler code to debug. The purpose of the code is to check whether a workspace exists in geoserver and if not to upload it. I have checked the code without docker (Windows 10) and it worked.

The directory I work on can be seen below:

[image]

File **main.py**

```
from geo.Geoserver import Geoserver

config= {
    "Username": "xxxx",
    "Password": "xxxx",
    "URL": "http://172.17.10.40:8080/geoserver"
}

host = config["URL"]
username = config["Username"]
password = config["Password"]
geo = Geoserver(host, username=username, password=password)

workspace='draft_ilias_v5'

if geo.get_workspace(workspace=workspace) is None:  # create workspace if not exists
    geo.create_workspace(workspace=workspace)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ENV TZ Europe/Athens

COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

WORKDIR work
COPY . /work

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "myenv", "python", "main.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  my_geoserver:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: geoserver

    networks:
      - draft_network

networks:
  draft_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 18.100.0.1/24
```

A user defined network was defined since there was a problem regarding the default docker ip range. I have used `docker compose build` to build the image and `docker compose up` to create the container. I got the following error using the latter command.

> geo.Geoserver.GeoserverException: Status : 404 - b"No such workspace:
> 'draft_ilias_v5' found"

[image]

I am not sure if I need to use ports in docker-compose file. I have tried to remove the if-condition at **main.py**, keeping only
`geo.create_workspace(workspace=workspace)`

and it worked. The error is related to `get_workspace`.
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I would expect a 404 if the workspace doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok. Why I don't get the error when I run it without Docker? Is it related to Linux environment of Docker?

Comment: Not sure, you probably need to look at the python code to see exactly what's happening